¿Cómo puedo hacer una gráfica radial para representar proporciones de diferentes grupos?
Este es el código que no me funciona. Este usa fmsb y lo intento con ggradar pero no lo puedo instalar. Se plantea inicialmente las proporciones para cada tratamiento y el control, luego los máximos y los mínimos, todos dispuestos como filas que se unen para colocarles nombres de columnas y así tener un formato de filas y columnas. Posteriormente se intenta hacer un grafico radial con la función radarchat del paquete fmsb.
library(ggplot2)
library(fmsb)
Nema_0.2<-c(60.42,38.52,0,1.04,0)
Nema_0.4<-c(3.125,96.875,0,0,0)
Nema_0.6<-c(12.44,86.18,0,1.38,0)
Ajo_2.5<-c(16.67,81.6 7,0,1,66,0)
Ajo_5<-c(3.92,94.78,0,0.65,0.65)
Hulk_0.2<-c(10.2,88.78,0,0.34,0.68)
Controlar<-c(10.40,89.60,0,0,0)
Máx<-c(100,100,100,100,100)
Mín<-c(0,0,0,0,0)
valores_clases <- data.frame(rbind(
 Nema_0.2,Nema_0.4,Nema_0.6,
Ajo_2.5, Ajo_5, Hulk_0.2, Control, Máx., Mín.
))
colnames(valores_clases)<-paste(c("Fitoparásitos", "Bacteriófagos", "Fungívoros", "Omnívoros", "Predadores"))
áreas <- c(rgb(1, 0, 0, 0,25),
 rgb(0, 1, 0, 0,25),
 rgb(0, 0, 1, 0,25),
 rgb(1, 1, 0, 0,25),
 rgb(1, 0, 1, 0,25),
 rgb(0, 1, 1, 0,25),
 RGB(0,5, 0,5, 0,5, 0,25))
radarchart(valores_clases,
 cglty = 1,
 cglcol = "gris",
 pcol = 2:8,
 plwd = 2,
 cantidad = 1,
 pfcol = áreas)

Este es el gráfico que busco obtener:

¡Mis saludos!
Sá, Farid Leonel.
